# How to send HTTP/2 headers immediately when using PHP-FPM and Apache

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, http2

I can't seem to be able to send headers immediately from PHP when running as FPM. They are sent only at the end of the request, along with the content.

I have an Apache + PHP-FPM setup. I have disabled output compression in PHP and Apache.

I've even looked into the TCP connection stream using `tcpdump -nn -i any -A -s 0 port 9000` and I've seen that PHP doesn't send the headers to Apache until the end, so the problem is with the PHP setup.

See below the test code that I'm using.

```php
header('Status: 200 OK');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

header('Link: </src/app/src/App/Ui/Layout/default.css?__mtime=1553684041>; rel=preload; as=style;', false);

flush();

header('Test: 1', false);
sleep(5);
header('Test2: 2', false);

echo 'test';
```

I would expect that the `Link:` header to be sent before the end of the request, i.e. before the `'test'` string but it isn't. All the headers are sent at the end of the request, after the `5` second delay.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably looking for [ob_flush](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).

Comment: @Dave It does not work either.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn’t work but ever thought about using 103 for this?

Comment: @BarryPollard `PHP does not support 103 Early Hints, because it doesn’t have a native ability to send more than 1 status code back to a client` - https://evertpot.com/http/103-early-hints

Answer (score -1):

By default `fastcgi_buffering` is set to `on`.

You need to add: `fastcgi_buffering off;` to the relevant `location` block.